# Set is open Conway

Tags: complex-analysis, metric-spaces, self-learning

I am reading Conway introduction to complex analysis. I don't understand why is $A$ open.  If $y \in B(a;1)$. It follows that

$$|y| <= |y - a| + |a| < 2$$

How does Conway get 1 ?[image]

Comment: It's not an openset in $\mathbb C$ but is an openset in $X$.

Comment: Why is it open in X ?

Comment: A set in $X$ is open iff it is $O\cap X$ for some open $O$ in $\mathbb C$. And $O=\{z:|z|<2\}$ here.

Comment: *In the metric space* $X$, $A$ is the open ball $B(0;1+\lambda)$ for all $0<\lambda<1$. It contains all elements of $X$ which are less than $1+\lambda$ away from $0$, and no other elements. And open balls are always open.